# underscore/lodash: how to filter out empty properties?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

How come I can't do this with underscore*?

```
_.omit({ foo: [] }, _.isEmpty);
```

I expect an empty object, i.e. `{}`, but it always returns what appears to be a copy of the unaltered source object.

`_.omit` is supposed to support a callback function, whose first argument will be the value of an item in the object (I don't care what the key is, I just want to drop key/value pairs where the value is empty).
http://underscorejs.org/#omit

`_.isEmpty` has a single parameter, and should ignore any others. It seems like a perfect match for a `_.omit` callback.
http://underscorejs.org/#isEmpty

** Note: I am actually using the lodash implementation (v.2.4.1) of the underscore API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Damn. I had the question written up, but that last line I wrote made me think again. I went back to http://underscorejs.org and opened the browser console, and ran my code snippet there. It performed as expected, returning an empty object!

I tried it with lodash 3.0.1 (released just two days ago!), and it also works as expected.

I've since confirmed that I can't get lodash 2.4.1's `_.omit` to work with *any* predicate function.

I guess there's a bug in lodash 2.4.1. That version was stable for quite a while, so I'm sure it's widespread, and I won't just throw away my question. Given the level of abstraction behind `_.omit`, I suspect that this bug affects other functions as well. I hope this helps someone.

Comment: You're looking for `_.omitBy` in Lodash. `_.omit` takes an object and array of properties.

Comment: Well, in lodash 2.4.1 and 3.0.1, this works as expected, and is the solution I ended up using: `var storable = _.omit(attrs, function (value) {
      return value === null || value === undefined;
    });`

Comment: I'll bet `_.omitBy` is a recent change in 4. Glad you got it working.